# Module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-ui;(unknown)

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am trying to run activator, but got this on my windows machine.

```
module not found: com.typesafe.activator#activator-ui;(unknown)
```

The [full log is](http://pastie.org/pastes/9416369/text?key=q9vpdyuzmodmtsutiigya)

OS : Windows 8

Comment: Also, on their website is shows (unknown version) of the activator http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted

Comment: There seems to be an ongoing issue right now. I'd say check back this Github issue in a while - https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from what I wrote on https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/608 :

This should be fixed now, it was a server-side problem returning a bad version. You may need to delete version-0.properties under ~/.activator if there's (unknown) or something stuck in there.

You can always force Activator not to update (to use whatever is already in version-0.properties) using activator -Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false, though this should be fixed now so that should not be needed. If you have no version-0.properties it will stick to the original version if you use -Dactivator.checkForUpdates=false.

Thanks for reporting!